# Node.js mysql callback error

Tags: mysql, node.js, callback

I Used node.js and mysql.
i Made callback function in mysql query callback.

```
exports.callback = function(req) 
{
....
    Mysqldb.pool.getConnection(function(err, db) {
        db.query("select * from tbl"), function (err,rows) {      
          db.query("update tbl set id = 1"), function (err, rows){
          }); //update tbl
       });//select tbl
    }); //getconnection
}; //export.callback
```

Error is update query callback....
error message is

```
TypeError: this._callback.apply is not a function
at Query.Sequence.end (c:\redfox_server_src\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:96:24)
at Query.ErrorPacket (c:\redfox_server_src\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:94:8)
at Protocol._parsePacket (c:\redfox_server_src\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:274:23)
at Parser.write (c:\redfox_server_src\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:77:12)
at Protocol.write (c:\redfox_server_src\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\redfox_server_src\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:96:28)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
```

please help me..

Answer (score 2):

You missed a double quotation mark here.

Wrong:

```
db.query("select * from tbl)
```

Right:

```
db.query("select * from tbl")
```